# JsTree Click Event

Tags: javascript, jstree

Hi I am new to JsTree and I got a question on event.
Let's call the tree structure stuff as LeftSide and the content rendered after you click one node on the tree as RightSide.
What I can do is that you click one node at LeftSide then there is a subpage will be rendered at RightSide.

Now, what I need is to click something on the RightSide (This "something" can be a node name on the LeftSide) and it will render a subpage on the RightSide as same as if you click that node on the LeftSide.

I am not sure whether I make my question clear.

The point is that I don't know how to describe my question and search it one the web. 
So if you don't know the exact answer, you you just tell me which direction I should search for it.
(If you tell me to read the official document, please specify which part rather than the whole doc.)

Appreciate for any help!!!

Comment: Is RightSide part of jsTree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to listen for the `select_node.jstree` event, and get the selected node(s). You can then do what you want to the right side of your page.

```
$("#jstree_id").on('select_node.jstree', function(e) {
    // gather ids of selected nodes
    var selected_ids = [];
    $("#jstree_id").jstree('get_selected').each(function () { 
        selected_ids.push(this.id); 
    }); 
    // do summit with them
    $('#RightSide').text('selected '+selected_ids);
});
```

Edited as `bind` has been deprecated in favour of `on`.

Comment: Wow, didn't expect anyone will answer this dinosaur question... I believe your solution works, though I have found my solution few months ago. Thanks for answering.

Comment: Thanks :). A lot of tutorials say you must use "on" but that does not work.

Comment: @BradBird that wasn't the point of this answer, only an effect of how old it was.`bind` is deprecated in jQuery 3.0.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the "select_node.jstree" event is the best solution, because when you refresh the tree, it also will be fire. The below snippet code is the way that I use：

```
$("#categories_tree").on("click", ".jstree-anchor", function(e) {
   var id = $("#categories_tree").jstree(true).get_node($(this)).id;
})
```

Edit: fixed a close bracket

Comment: This is a better answer because pressing back it will fire off with the accepted answer.